# Cassandra service doesn't start

Tags: database, ubuntu, service, cassandra

for some reason i tried to reinstall the cassandra ,

firstlly i tried this to remove cassandra:

> sudo apt-get remove cassandra

and after that i removed the cassandra folders on :

> /var/lib/cassandra
>
> /var/log/cassandra
>
> /etc/cassandra

using `rm -rf` command

after reinstalling cassandra 1.2.8 ,the cassandra service doesn't start
and

> sudo service cassandra start

doesn't work ,

what can i do to resolve this problem?

thanks in advance,

---

`java version = 1.6.0_27`

`os = ubuntu 12.04`

Comment: What does your cassandra log say?

Comment: the log file is empty

Comment: Are you sure that the cassandra user has read and write access to the lib and log directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried to `purge` a cassandra instead `remove` and installing again so it works now